# Is it possible to obtain Facebook API access token server-side?

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to integrate a Facebook news feed into a website  using Facebook C# SDK https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk

```
var client = new FacebookClient("token");
dynamic me = client.Get("username/feed");
```

I have not been able to find any examples of generating an access token at runtime. All examples seem to be targeted at client apps where a used would be required to authorise the application.

Based on what I've seen so far, there used to be a way to generate a permanent access token (using `offline_access` permission), but as of 2nd May 2012 that approach is deprecated.

At the moment, I am not sure this is even a supported scenario.

Is it possible to get Facebook news feed entirely using server-side code with no user involvement?

**EDIT:** Looks like there might be a way: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token
Will try later and report back.

Comment: Is your question "how to obtain access token servers side if I have user name/password" OR "how to read feed when I have access token" OR "how to send access token from browser to my server"?

Comment: I think it's 'how do i get a valid access token for a user without them having to come back to my app' - which is covered in the offline_access deprecation info, they need to come back once every 60 days to keep the tokens alive

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have updated the question title. I know how to get the feed. I don't know how to get a permanent (or renewable) token.

Comment: No, it is not possible, you must use Oauth to get the user to authorised your app and for your app to obtain an access token - the Edit you added there is referring to the long-term access tokens i mentioned (currently 60 days maximum validity)

Comment: No I don't know. Your new question sounds like a bad idea to me - following correct client side OAuth route would be better than trying to cheat by logging in from server using user name/password.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't plan on going down this route, just investigating what is possible. It is probably worth mentioning, this whole thing was to provide fallback content for site visitors who don't have javascript enabled. The site would pull feed from a single specific FB account, not query individual users for their details.

Comment: Users who disabled JS don't care about social networking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, you can't do anything with username/password.  the user has to enter these into facebook's login ui and click the button to agree to letting your code do whatever it's asking to do.

Comment: +1. One obviously can cheat and automate the UI if have user name/password at hand... But asking for user name/password for third party site is not nice.